# How can VSCode load .js.map to view/edit js file?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code

I am debugging a close sourced VSCode extension. There is `extension.js` and `extension.js.map` file.

But, when I open `extension.js` file, I found there is (nearly) no way to see unminified source(I mean, the real source).

Is there any extension that load `.js.map` when I open a `.js` file?

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 0):

I can't find an extension can view/edit `.js` file with `.js.map` assosicated.

You could try [reverse-sourcemap](https://www.npmjs.com/package/reverse-sourcemap). use reverse-sourcemap to generate source file(s), and browse them.